# FreeRadius with Samba 4 using NTLM

Tags: ntlm, samba, freeradius

I was following this tutorial:
http://wiki.freeradius.org/guide/freeradius-active-directory-integration-howto
to setup AD integration but I am still experiencing problem with FreeRadius.

When I use

```
radtest -t mschap "username" "password" localhost 1812 testing123
```

it returns:

```
Received Access-Reject Id 250 from 127.0.0.1:1812 to 127.0.0.1:59482 length 38
        MS-CHAP-Error = '\000E=691 R=1'
(0) -: Expected Access-Accept got Access-Reject
```

Anyway when I try(NTLM String should be correct):

```
sudo -u radiusd ntlm_auth --username="MyUserName" --request-nt-key
Password:
NT_STATUS_OK: Success (0x0)
```

When I start `radiusd -X` I can see errors:

```
(1)  mschap : EXPAND --challenge=%{%{mschap:Challenge}:-00}
(1)  mschap :    --> --challenge=4052dcf90b2dec2c
(1)  mschap : EXPAND --nt-response=%{%{mschap:NT-Response}:-00}
(1)  mschap :    --> --nt-response=617c94e4b57451ef769181355abf9a297ba5bb05d1938891
Program returned code (1) and output 'Logon failure (0xc000006d)'
(1)  mschap : External script failed
(1)  ERROR: mschap : External script says: Logon failure (0xc000006d)
(1)  ERROR: mschap : MS-CHAP-Response is incorrect
(1)   [mschap] = reject
(1)  } # Auth-Type MS-CHAP = reject
(1) Failed to authenticate the user
```

But I was not able to find any solutions. Any idea how to debug this or what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

the 'return code' (0xc000006d) indicate that the ntlm_auth script don't authenticate the provided credentials and exit with code 1. So, I would try to 'hard code' the ntlm_auth in the mods-available/mschap with your control items and add item by item. E.g.:

```
ntlm_auth = 'ntlm_auth --username="MyUserName" --request-nt-key --password="MyUserPassword"'
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, I tried your suggestion and now I am getting: Program returned code (2) and output 'Failed to execute "ntlm_auth": Permission denied'
(0)  mschap : External script failed
(0)  ERROR: mschap : External script says: Failed to execute "ntlm_auth": Permission denied
(0)  ERROR: mschap : MS-CHAP-Response is incorrect  ... So It has to be something with permissions?

Comment: Ok, I fixed permission exeption by running radiusd as root, anyway it is not working as expected. I "hard coded" mschap module with working NTLM command (from shell) and it returns: 
Program returned code (0) and output 'NT_STATUS_OK: Success (0x0)'
(0)  ERROR: mschap : Invalid output from ntlm_auth: expecting 'NT_KEY: ' prefix
(0)  ERROR: mschap : MS-CHAP-Response is incorrect
Any idea?

Comment: @AdamDrabek sorry to hear. Seems to be my fault. Sorry. Did you tried with `--challenge=%{%{mschap:Challenge}:-00} --nt-response=%{%{mschap:NT-Response}:-00}` from [your provided manual](http://wiki.freeradius.org/guide/freeradius-active-directory-integration-howto#introduction_mods-available-mschap)? When I add this both items it worked for me.